# Salesforce Rest API Authorize By Connected App OAuth 2.0

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, salesforce

Now, I have created a connected app, selected some oauth scopes, set a callbackUrl(https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success).

Then add it to the package, bulid a release package.
When install the package in the **Professional/Group** Edition, I invoke the rest API, obviously, it failed , then the authorize starts work

> (The url is https :// ap2.salesforce.com /services /oauth2
>   /authorize?response_type = code&scope = full + refresh_token &
>   client_id = {0}&redirect_uri = https :// login.salesforce.com
>   /services/oauth2/success).

But it looks not work, and dispaly a message

> 'Remote Access Application Authorization'.

In Expection， I want this.

click allow authorize, deny not.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube: [Salesforce Rest API using oAuth 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULWBdjJx1Ss)

STEP 1: Create OAuth APP on Salesforce developer portal [ Will create video for this too  ]

STEP2: Make the following things handy
   CONSUMER KEY
   CONSUMER SECRET
 Hit following url with CONSUMER_KEY as clientId

https://login.salesforce.com/services... CONSUMER_KEY&redirect_uri=http://tagbin.in/

in response it will return code in the callback URI, keep that handy too

STEP 3: Now we need to exchange this code for access token, hit the following URI, POST request

https://login.salesforce.com/services...

POST PARAMS (URL ENCODED PARAMS) : 
code=CODE_FROM_STEP_2&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=CONSUMER_KEY&client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftagbin.in%2F

this will return a json, make handy 2 of the JSON key:
-access_token
-instance_url

Now you can use this access_token to hit all endpoint on salesforce